# Autofocus on each textbox when not required field

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, required, autofocus

I have a page with multiple text boxes, all of which are not required fields (i.e. the user can fill out as many as they wish to). However, I am not able to get autofocus to work from the second text box onwards and the form submits instead when I press enter to move into the next text box (probably because the inputs are not required). Is there a way such that I will be able to autofocus into the next text box after keying in the response for the previous textbox even if the field is not required/stop the form from submitting? Thanks for any help!

```html
<html>
 <main>
  <form>

     <br><label for="response1"><b>Animals</b></label><br>
     <input type="text" id="response1" name="response1" autocomplete="off" autofocus ></br>

     <br><input type="text" id="response2" name="response2" autocomplete="off" ></br>

     <br><input type="text" id="response3" name="response3" autocomplete="off" ></br>

     <br><input type="text" id="response4" name="response4" autocomplete="off" > </br>

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </main>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this, its supposed to make the enter to submit only on the last input, and the other times it just moves to the next input.

Dont forget to add the onkeydown to all the inputs except the last one.

```html
<form>
  <br><label for="response1"><b>Animals</b></label><br>
  <input type="text" id="response1" name="response1" autocomplete="off" autofocus onkeydown="next(this, event)"></br>
  <br><input type="text" id="response2" name="response2" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="next(this, event)"></br>
  <br><input type="text" id="response3" name="response3" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="next(this, event)"></br>
  <br><input type="text" id="response4" name="response4" autocomplete="off"> </br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function next(currElement, e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let nextNum = parseInt(currElement.id.substr(8)) + 1;

      document.getElementById('response' + nextNum).focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```